# TypeError after float to string conversion

Tags: python

i'm writing my first program in python. I have a function that should save a number in a txt file. This number is obtained with some math, converted in int, (just because i need only the integer part) then in string. Then saved into txt.

Here i just deleted the saving part and replaced with print.

```
str=140

str0 = float(str0)
str = float(str)
perc0 = 100-(str*100/str0)
perc0 = int(perc0)
perc0 = str(perc0)
print(perc0)
```

But the result is

```
File ".\temp.py", line 10, in <module>
perc0 = str(perc0)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

What am i doing wrong?
Sorry for dumb question, but after some research i don't really know what's wrong, meybe i'm missing some basics

Comment: don't use str as a variable as str is a protected keyword in python. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Comment: You are using a protected keyword (```str```) for your variable name. Change that and it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` is a keyword in python. You should avoid using that as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks. as i said i was sure it was a dumb error...